# Class with the hashcode function

Tags: java, hashcode

I would like to check if the `hashcode` function is used in the right way in the above code. I noticed that the `map` has some strange null and 0 values instead of {1,2,3}.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3}; 
    Map<Row, Integer> map = map(array);
}

static class Row extends Object {
        private int value;
        private volatile int hashCode = 0;

        public Row(int val) {
            this.value = val;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(this == obj)
                return true;
            if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
                return false;
            // object must be Row at this point
            Row row = (Row)obj;
                return (value == row.value);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode () {
            final int multiplier = 7;
            if (hashCode == 0) {
                int code = 31;
                code = multiplier * code + value;
                hashCode = code;
            }
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    private static Map<Row, Integer> map(int[] array) {
          Map<Row, Integer> arrayMap = new HashMap<Row, Integer>();
          for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
                arrayMap.put(new Row(array[i]), i);
          return arrayMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no flaw in the above code. Why don't you include the code that you used to see the null and zero values and also show us the exact output of that code? ("some strange null and 0 values" is kinda vague, don't you think?) Better yet, why don't you just turn this into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can try it ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashCode looks correct to me, except the value field should be final to make the class immutable and thus thread-safe, but it's way too complex. The `Row` is just a wrapper for an int value. The `hashCode` could be reduced to:

```
return this.value;
```

Or you could avoid the `Row` class completely, and use an `Integer` to wrap your int value.

Answer (score 4):

What problems are you exactly having? If I add a `toString` method to the `Row` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(value);
}
```

And print the map afterwards:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Map<Row, Integer> map = map(array);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

It prints: `{3=2, 1=0, 2=1}`. That seems correct.

Comment: I'm solving the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789979/code-for-searching-similar-entires-in-multiple-two-dimensional-arrays. And the code does not work correctly. I performed debugging and came to conclusion that something is wrong with the hashcode function.