# Code for finding similar rows in two-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

I´m trying to find **similar rows in multiple two-dimensional arrays** as it was described in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787989/find-similar-rows-in-3-two-dimensional-arrays). For the below-given example, the answer is `false, true,` although it should be `false, false`.

Another very important question is how to adjust this code to arrays *with the different number of rows*.

I appreciate very much any help. Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer[]> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer[]> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        ArrayList<Integer[]> array3 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        array1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3}); array1.add(new Integer[]{1,0,3});
        array2.add(new Integer[]{1,0,3}); array2.add(new Integer[]{0,0,3});
        array3.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3}); array3.add(new Integer[]{0,3,3});
        for (int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++) {
            boolean answ = equalRows(array1.get(i),array2.get(i),array3.get(i));
            System.out.println(answ);
        }
    }
    
    static class Row extends Object {
        private int value;
        
        public Row(int val) {
            this.value = val;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(this == obj)
                return true;
            if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
                return false;
            // object must be Row at this point
            Row row = (Row)obj;
                return (value == row.value);
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode () {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    private static Map<Row, Integer> map(Integer[] row) {
          Map<Row, Integer> rowMap = new HashMap<Row, Integer>();
          for (int i=0; i<row.length; i++)
              rowMap.put(new Row(row[i]), i);
          return rowMap;
    }

    private static boolean equalRows(Integer[] row1, Integer[] row2, Integer[] row3){
           Map<Row, Integer> map1 = map(row1);
           Map<Row, Integer> map2 = map(row2);

           for (int i=0; i<row3.length; i++){
              Row row = new Row(row3[i]);
              Integer result1 = map1.get(row);
              Integer result2 = map2.get(row);
              if (result1 == null || result2 == null) {
                  return false;
              }
           }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Edit#1**
In the first test I´m comparing {1,2,3}, {1,0,3} and {1,2,3}. In the second: {1,0,3}, {0,0,3}, {0,3,3}. The problem with the second row is that {0,0,3} and {0,3,3} are tackled as {0,3}. I don´t know how to modify the code to deferentiate between {0,0,3} and {0,3,3} (I still should use HashMap).

**Edit#2**
The idea is that first I take rows from array1 and array2 and I put them into maps. Then I take a row from array3 and try to find it in maps. If I can´t find it in any of these maps, then it means that rows are not similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two arrays, ignoring nulls you can have

```
public static <T> boolean equalsExceptForNulls(T[] ts1, T[] ts2) {
    if (ts1.length != ts2.length) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < ts1.length; i++) {
       T t1 = ts1[i], t2 = ts2[i];
       if (t1 != null && t2 != null && !t1.equals(t2)) 
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static <T> boolean equalsExceptForNulls3(T[] ts1, T[] ts2, T[] ts3) {
    return equalsExceptForNulls(ts1, ts2) && 
           equalsExceptForNulls(ts1, ts3) && 
           equalsExceptForNulls(ts2, ts3);
}
// or generically
public static <T> boolean equalsExceptForNulls(T[]... tss) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tss.length - 1; i++)
       for(int j = i + 1; i < tss.length; j++)
           if(!equalsExceptForNulls(tss[i], tss[j]) 
               return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

The problem you have is that array3 is being used to determine which rows to compare.

In the first test you are comparing rows 1,2,3 and the second test you are comparing rows 0 and 3.  The first test should be false and the second should be true.

I found the issue by stepping through your code in a debugger. I suggest you do the same.

I would also use `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`

Comment: In the first test I´m comparing {1,2,3}, {1,0,3} and {1,2,3}. In the second: {1,0,3}, {0,0,3}, {0,3,3}. The problem with the second row is that {0,0,3} and {0,3,3} are tackled as {0,3}. I don´t know how to modify the code to deferentiate {0,0,3} and {0,3,3} (I still should use HashMap).

Comment: But you are not comparing the three arrays, you are only comparing the first two arrays, the third array is being used to determine which rows to compare.  I don't understand why you are using `Row` or a `HashMap` at all.  I can only assume its homework, so I have no idea how to change your code without re-writing it.

Comment: You have to clearly define what you are trying to do and ensure your code is doing that in a debugger.  You should try to make it clear in your code what you are trying to achieve and why you have made the choices you have.

Comment: The idea is that first I take rows from array1 and array2 and I put them into maps. Then I take a row from array3 and try to find it in maps. If I can´t find them, then it means that rows are not similar.

Comment: How about trying `Arrays.equals(array1, array2) && Arrays.equals(array1, array3)` ?  What do you mean by similar? How different can they be but still be similar?

Comment: I need to compare arrays by rows. It mean that I take ith rows in arrays and compare them with one other. For instance, for the rows array1[i]: {1,2,3}, array2[i]: {1,2,3} and array3[i]: {1,2,3} the answer should be true. But for array1[i]: {1,2,3}, array1[i]: {1,2,3} and array3[i]: {2,2,2} the answer should be false.

Comment: That's what Arrays.equals() does. `Arrays.equals(new int[] { 1,2,3 }, new int[] { 1,2,3 })` is `true` and `Arrays.equals(new int[] { 1,2,3 }, new int[] { 1,2,4 })` is `false`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6574/discussion-between-klausos-klausos-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish but could it be that your problem lies in the method

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
            return false;
        // object must be Row at this point
        Row row = (Row)obj;
            return (value == row.value);
    }
```

because with

```
if(this == obj)
```

for example you want to have an value comparison - But what you get using the "==" comperator is a comparison of two objects references ?

So maybe

```
if(this.equals(obj))
```

is what you want ?

Furthermore, have you tried to step through your code in debugging mode statement per statement ? I guess doiing so could locate your fault quickly ...

cheers :)

Comment: `if(this.equals(obj))` is what this method is trying to implement. If you called this it would go into an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, I did degugging, and I found out that HashMap does not allow to keep similar entries, e.g. instead of {0,0,3} and {0,3,3} it will keep {0,3}. So, these rows become similar, although they are different. I got stuck with this code...I need just to find really similar rows in multiple two-dimensional arrays. That´s it.

Comment: oh yeah you're right! I didn't notice that he is overriding the equals-method .. Well, it was a try :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic problem with your approach which leads to this bug. You are using a map to determine the position of an element in the other rows. When constructing the map if there are duplicate elements in the rows, their previous indices will be overwitten. This is exactly what is happening in your case. There is a duplcate zero in the second row of second array.

here is what the maps look like for the second row

```
map1 = ((Row(1), 0), (Row(0), 1), (Row(3), 3))
map2 = ((Row(0), 1), (Row(3), 3))
```

Nnotice there are only two elements in map2 bcoz the first one was overwitten with the second one. When you do a lookup with the elements of the second row from the third array the lookup always succeeds (because it it looks only for a 0 and a 3 and never for a 1)

Moreover the condition you check for failure is incomplete i.e

```
if (result1 == null || result2 == null) {
    return false;
}
```

should be

```
if (result1 == null || result2 == null || !result1.equals(i) || !result2.equals(i)) {
    return false;
}
```

In my opinion you shouldn't be using a map at all. Instead compare each element one by one. To generalize the code for arrays of different lengths try using size() method of the ArrayList class.

If is important to you that a map should be used, then you should use the index of each array element as the key and the Row object as the value instead of doing the reverse.